# Page created by module as node

Tags: nodes, 7

I have created some pages by writting custom module using hook_menu; those pages were hard-coded in content type template files before. But now, i miss some node functionality, template elements like social blocks (service links), comments etc.

Could module somehow register the page as part of content type (mimic itself as node of content type), or could i inject the page from module inside content type ?

Thanks for your clues!

Comment: Not sure it's quite a duplicate but [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27599/is-it-possible-to-have-pseudo-nodes) seems somewhat related

Comment: From the one side of my question, that post contains answer, but it seems a bit complicated. From the other side, could i just create node, and invoke module to throw content in it. I did that kind of tricks with some blocks, probably it should work with pages too... thanks.